What is the reference time point relative to which the capital-gain and capital-loss features of the UC Irvine Adults dataset are measured?
The Adults dataset available in the UC Irvine Machine Learning Repository is based on the 1994 census data (USA census, I presume).
The dataset has two features named capital-gain and capital-loss. What is the reference time point relative to which these features are measured?
For instance, the capital-gain of record no. 0 is 2174. So, at the time the census was taken, the person represented by this record had gained $2174. My question is: gained since when? A person's capital fluctuates throughout their life. So what is the time point at which the baseline capital was noted, relative to which the gain was measured at the time the census was taken?
